# Interesting AOP question on a cross cutting concern?

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop

Consider a set of DOAs with methods similar to this

```
public void addObject(Long sessionId, Long clientId, Dom obj){...}
```

Now every domain pojo (`Dom`) has a `sessionId` property and for every insert, update or delete on a domain object a `sessionId` must be passed with `setSessionId(Long sessionId)`so we can know who does what. But it seems that this cuts across the all the data access stuff we and I think AOP would be a good tool to insert the `sessionId` in either a `@Before(JoinPoint)` or `@Around(ProceedingJoinPoint)` advise. Is this actually feasible? The DAOs are mostly Hibernate based with a few Spring `StoredProcedure`.

Comment: I'm confused... if the sessionId is part of the Dom object, why is it also a parameter in the DAo method?

Comment: Ooops my mistake but to clarify the sessionId gets set manually(programmatically) in the code, but the method above is a proposed solution where AOP can just insert the sessionId without the developer having to deal with it. The method signature is incorrect though as something will need to be passed into the method for sessionId. The advise would retrieve the sessionId from utility code and just insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sessionId parameter seem to belong to an **audit aspect**. In Hibernate, this auditing aspect is typically implemented in an implementation of [org.hibernate.Interceptor](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html).

You can implement many methods that correspond to life-cycle event for your entities and queries. In your implementation, it is easy to get access to your current sessionId (it could use a ThreadLocal variable). Clear and clean, fast ;-)

This is probably simpler than doing it yourself with AOP, especially as you get callbacks from Hibernate for life-cycle events.

Answer (score 1):

An interceptor around your DAO layer will have trouble accounting for transitive persistence, i.e. hibernate operations (save, delete, ...) cascading to associated entities. A Hibernate session interceptor could.

In any case, if your interceptor can somehow discover the current session id, this is possible to do either way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you couldn't do this, I've actually done something similar (a little more complex) in the past, helped me not cross-refactor every class!

Have you thought of putting
public void addObject(Long sessionId, Long clientId, Dom obj){...}
in an father / upper level class? This method could delegate on each implementation..